# How to create custom extractor (column definition type) in AEM (CQ5) reporting?

Tags: report, aem

By adobe docs, it is clear to create simple reports ([Adobe Docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/operations/dev-reports.html#par_text_33))

But how to create extractor for a column, which can convert date value to "week start to week end" (4 Jan 16 to 10 Jan 16) ?

The output should be sortable, i.e. not using clientFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to extend the functionalities in AEM reports.

> Transforms the results returned by the initial query (reportbase) into the basic result set using value extractors.
>   Value extractors are automatically chosen depending on the column type. They are used for reading values from the underlying JCR Query and creating a result set from them; after which further processing may then be applied. For example, for the diff type, the value extractor reads two properties, calculates the single value that is then added to the result set. **The value extractors cannot be configured.**

Hence, ended up saving another property in data source node, with formatted data instead of extracting formatted data.